# Python Iteration Through Lists with Stepped Progression

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

Given the following lists:

```
letters = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')
numbers = ('1', '2', '3', '4')
```

How can I produce an iterated list that produces the following:

```
output = [('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3'), ('d', '4'), 
          ('e', '1'), ('f', '2'), ('g', '3'), ('a', '4'),
          ('b', '1'), ('c', '2'), ('d', '3'), ('e', '4'),
          ('f', '1'), ('g', '2')...]
```

I feel like I should be able to produce the desired output by using

```
output = (list(zip(letters, itertools.cycle(numbers))
```

But this produces the following:

```
output = [('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3'), ('d', '4'),
          ('e', '1'), ('f', '2'), ('g', '3')]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want `output` to be infinite?

Comment: Great question, it can be infinite or tied to a for/while loop, I think my biggest point of confusion is how to have the output list step through possibilities rather than terminating once the longest list is satisfied with values supplied by the cycle().

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an infinite generator, you can use `cycle` with `zip` for both lists, in the form of `zip(itertools.cycle(x), itertools.cycle(y))`. That would supply you with the required generator:

```
>>> for x in zip(itertools.cycle(letters), itertools.cycle(numbers)):
...     print(x)
...
('a', '1')
('b', '2')
('c', '3')
('d', '4')
('e', '1')
('f', '2')
('g', '3')
('a', '4')
('b', '1')
('c', '2')
('d', '3')
...
```

Comment: perhaps add a sentinel value no to end in an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

If you want a finite list of elements, this should work

```
import itertools

letters = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')
numbers = ('1', '2', '3', '4')
max_elems = 10

list(itertools.islice((zip(itertools.cycle(letters), itertools.cycle(numbers))), max_elems))
```

results in

```
[('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3'), ('d', '4'), ('e', '1'), ('f', '2'), ('g', '3'), ('a', '4'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '2')]
```